# how to convert hours:min:sec to dec number in android studio

Tags: android, time

I am building an Android Studio code that is supposed to calculate the user's hours of work by the hourly pay he receives.
I need to convert the number of hours to numeric value - DEC, and also reverse.
Is there any library that can help with that?

I'm pretty new so I'll glad if it was simple and understandable.
thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a little vague, so I am going to make a lot of assumptions.

1. I am assuming you mean: If a guy make a 100 dollars at 10 dollars an hour, how many hours did he work?
2. I am assuming you would like to go the opposite way, stating if a guy works 10 hours at 10 dollars an hour, how much did he make?

To accomplish this goal, you really do not need to convert hours to a decimal scale. For the first assumption, you would use a formula like so:

Total/per hour.
This would look something like

```
float total = 100.00;
float pHour = 10.00;
float hours = total/pHour;
```

On the second assumption, you could just rearrange the terms to where you would have;

```
float total = hours*pHour
```

If this does not match what you are asking, there are plenty of websites that will show you conversion formulas. Implementing these into a java program are usually as straight forward as my example. Now if you want to make the values user inputted or update on a database or anything else, there are also plenty of options and tutorials on how to do so.

In addition, please give more detail and be extremely clear when writing your question. There are answers for everything.